# Help needed to find the Sum of an infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The infinite series is convergent but l don't know where to start in order to sum it up. How do we know if it can be solved or can we only find an approximate answer ?

$$S= \frac1{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}+ \frac1{7\cdot 9\cdot 11}+\frac1{13\cdot 15 \cdot 17}+.......$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are interested in the following series:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(6\,k - 1)\,(6\,k - 3)\,(6\,k - 5)} 
& = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{8}\,\frac{1}{6\,k - 1} - \frac{1}{4}\,\frac{1}{6\,k - 3} + \frac{1}{8}\,\frac{1}{6\,k - 5}\right) \\
& = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left[ \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{8}\,x^{6k-2} - \frac{1}{4}\,x^{6k-4} + \frac{1}{8}\,x^{6k-6}\right)\text{d}x \right] \\
& = \int_0^1 \left[\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{8}\,x^{6k-2} - \frac{1}{4}\,x^{6k-4} + \frac{1}{8}\,x^{6k-6}\right)\right]\text{d}x \\
& = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}x^{6k-2} - \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} x^{6k-4} + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} x^{6k-6}\right)\text{d}x \\
& = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{8}\,\frac{x^4}{1 - x^6} - \frac{1}{4}\,\frac{x^2}{1 - x^6} + \frac{1}{8}\,\frac{1}{1 - x^6}\right)\text{d}x \\
& = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^2}{8\left(x^2+x+1\right)\left(x^2-x+1\right)}\,\text{d}x \\
& = \left. \frac{1}{16}\,\ln\left|\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x+1}\right| \right|_0^1 \\
& = \frac{\ln(3)}{16}\,.
\end{aligned} 
$$

Comment: Is that calculated with the help of a computer program, are there any general methods of solving it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw, it will provide me some ideas of working backwards to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.